# Should this CSS code be needed certainly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a simple webpage. This page has two picture. Above one is 100% opacity, and below one is 50% opacity. And when I scroll down the webpage, opacity of below picture turns 100% in 2 seconds.

I wrote codes, but they didn't work in my intent.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var el = document.querySelector('.show-on-scroll');
    if(window.scrollY >= 400) el.classList.add('shown');
    else el.classList.remove('shown');
});
```

```css
.show-on-scroll {/*below picture should not be shown*/
 animation: fadeout 2s;
 
}
.show-on-scroll.shown { /*below picture should be shown */
 animation: fadein 2s;
 
}
@keyframes fadein{
 from {opacity:0.5;}
 to {opacity:1;}
}
@keyframes fadeout{
 from {opacity:1;}
 to {opacity:0.5;}
}
```

```html
<div id="khuimage">
</div>
 
<div id="macbookimage" class="show-on-scroll">
</div>
```

In this way, If I scroll down and up, the second picture (macbookimage) fade out and **suddenly below picture appear**. This appearance is not my intent.

Below is my modified CSS code, and it works well in my intent.

```css
.show-on-scroll {/*below picture should not be shown*/
    animation: fadeout 2s;
    opacity:0.5;
}
.show-on-scroll.shown { /*below picture should be shown */
    animation: fadein 2s;
    opacity:1;
}
```

Do I have to write these opacity codes to represent my webpage? Why did the 1st case not work to my intent?

Comment: Instead of using an animation and keyframes, you could simply set an opacity of 0.5 and a transition on opacity of 2s on the below image and then give the shown class an opacity of 1.

Comment: I agree with Jake. You should not use `animation` in this case, if you do not have a fair reason to do so. Use `transition`

Comment: @Jake  Thank you!

Comment: @yunzen I got it! thank you:)

Comment: @YoonjongLee Glad I could help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` into the class `.show-on-scroll` in order to make it stay at the final keyframe

The default value of `animation-fill-mode` is `none`, which doesn't apply the style after the animation ends

ref: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp

Comment: @krugtep But I have one more question. If I refresh the webpage, second picture show in 100% opacity and it turns 50% opacity. How to make second picture in 50% opacity at first?

Comment: @YoonjongLee If your intention is to use keyframe, the only way to achieve this is to put `opacity: 0.5` as a default in a class `.show-on-scroll`.

This is not the best way to handle a simple animation tho. You can simply use `transition-duration` prop

check this pen: https://codepen.io/krugtep/pen/LvexeB

Comment: It was so simple problem in reality! :) I didn't know that solution. Thank you very much for your help!!!! I think I need a lot of study :)

Answer (score 1):

You should add `both` to the `animation` property

This is a shorthand for using the [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) property

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var el = document.querySelector('.show-on-scroll');
  if (window.scrollY >= 400) el.classList.add('shown');
  else el.classList.remove('shown');
});
```

```css
#khuimage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 1;
}

#macbookimage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: .5;
}

.show-on-scroll {
  /*below picture should not be shown*/
  animation: fadeout 2s both;
}

.show-on-scroll.shown {
  /*below picture should be shown */
  animation: fadein 2s both;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="khuimage"></div>

<div id="macbookimage" class="show-on-scroll"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you need to do here is to toggle the CSS class based on your scroll position.

You can solve it 2 ways in JS - by reading and evaluating the scroll position or with new and shiny IntersectionObserver. I have prepared working example for the 1st option, where I do toggle the class if scrollY is bigger than 1300. As you can see I am also using a boolean flag which prevents the function from generating excesive runs.

```
let isVisible = false

function toggleVisibility(target) {
    const myImage = document.querySelector(target)

  if (myImage.classList.contains('show')) {
    myImage.classList.remove('show')
    isVisible = false
  } else {
    myImage.classList.add('show')
    isVisible = true
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    console.log(window.scrollY)

  if(window.scrollY > 1300 && isVisible === false) {
    toggleVisibility('.my-image')
  } else if (window.scrollY < 1300 && isVisible === true) {
    toggleVisibility('.my-image')
  }
})
```

I have prepared a JSfiddle for you with working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/mkbctrlll/hntz8eub/68/
(It might be worth to increase the height of the output window, to actually see the change)

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't working on your end because you never fire the scroll event.
Just set the document height to test this.

```
<div style="height: 2999px">
 <div id="khuimage">
    </div>

    <div id="macbookimage" class="show-on-scroll">
    </div>

</div>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
            var el = document.querySelector('.show-on-scroll');
            console.log('HERE ', el.classList);
            if(window.scrollY >= 400) {el.classList.add('shown');
            console.log('HERE ', el.classList);
             }
             else { el.classList.remove('shown'); }
        });
    </script>
```

[image: This works, seems]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Safari as your browser then you need to add "@-webkit-keyframes" for keyframes.